# How can I get exit code of program run with perf stat?

Tags: linux, bash, exit-code, perf

I have to get statistics of some programs with perf stat i.e

`perf stat -o stat.log ./a.out`

I also have to get exit codes of those programs, as they will not always exit with 0. Let's say I have simple program that will return SIGSEGV:

`main(){*(int*)0=0;}`

Now when I run it I get:

`$ ./a.out
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
$ echo $?
139`

When I run it with perf however i get

`$ perf stat -o stat.log ./a.out
./a.out: Segmentation fault
$ echo $?
0`

I get 0, as if program finished without errors.

How can i get exit code of of a.out when I run it with perf stat?

EDIT: a.out is blackbox, I can't modify it in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Short Answer:

`perf stat` automatically returns the exit code of the program that it is running.  The problem is that you are trying to get the return code from your shell.

#### Longer answer:

What is happening in your example is that when you run your `./a.out` program it produces a segfault.  Bash (or whatever your shell is) catches the segfault and it sets the return value appropriately.

When you run the command with `perf stat` is does not set the exit code for a program that segfaults.  So instead you get a 0 exit code for perf itself exiting correctly (it could be misleading for perf to set the exit code to that of segfault because perf didn't segfault in this case).

To get the segfault (or other abnormal termination) exit code results you can use a helper script to get the return code from your shell and then return that to perf.  For example the following worked for me:

```
#!/bin/bash
`/bin/bash -c "$@"`
```

Using this `wrapper.sh` script to call your `./a.out` program using `perf stat` gives the desired return code of `139`.

```
$ perf stat ./wrapper.sh ./a.out 

Performance counter stats for './wrapper.sh ./a.out':

          9.959972      task-clock (msec)         #    0.766 CPUs utilized          
                 5      context-switches          #    0.502 K/sec                  
                 3      cpu-migrations            #    0.301 K/sec                  
               464      page-faults               #    0.047 M/sec                  
        16,413,813      cycles                    #    1.648 GHz                    
         7,262,551      stalled-cycles-frontend   #   44.25% frontend cycles idle   
         4,830,727      stalled-cycles-backend    #   29.43% backend  cycles idle   
        22,785,421      instructions              #    1.39  insns per cycle        
                                                  #    0.32  stalled cycles per insn
         4,699,645      branches                  #  471.853 M/sec                  
           124,437      branch-misses             #    2.65% of all branches        

       0.013010875 seconds time elapsed

$ echo $?
139
```

Comment: With this solution I can get the exit code, however, aren't I loosing accuracy, as perf will also count execution of wrapper script? From some fast mesurements it looks like I get around 3-4kk additional instructions (I checked only instruction count, as it is most important to me right now). I will have to check if this value is more or less constant and if it is significant in my use cases.

Comment: After some tests it looks like it is insignificant and I can use this solution.

Answer (score 0):

you probably get 0 exit code because `perf stat` finished running successfully.
you should get the exit code in `a.out`, right after the command you are executing.

Comment: OP knows that that is *what* needs to be done. The question is *how* to do it.

Comment: I can't modify a.out.